# Trigger a function once a REST request has completed

Tags: ember.js

While setting up the application router, I am requesting some data to the backend:

```
App.Node = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    processReply: function ( ) { do some processing here; },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this.cache = App.Node.find();
    }
});
```

Now, when the result of the `find` is received from the backend, I would like to do some data processing, by calling `this.processReply()`

How can I listen to the completion of the `find` request? I have tried plugging in to the `.then` method (assuming `find` returns a promise), but this is blocking my application.

```
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        var _this = this;
        this.cache = App.Node.find().then(function(data) {
          _this.process();
        });
    }
```

Comment: you where right, deleted my answer since it does not apply in your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setupController` is synchronous unlike the `model` hooks. You can delay setting the content of the controller from the promise's then. So the bindings/computed properties from the controller fire after the data has loaded.

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  App.Node.find().then(function(data) {
    controller.set('content', data);
    // optionally
    // controller.process()
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darshan, but I do not understand it. Is it not the job of `find` to set the content of the controller? The controller corresponding to `App.Node` is not necessarily the controller that I have in `setupController`. In my original implementation I am **not** setting the content of the controller. Why should I be forced to do it when listening to the `then`? I was expecting to be able to hook into the `.then` of the promise without causing any side effects to the way that ember internally handles the promise, eventually by having to return a value (promise?) from my handling of the `then`.

Comment: `Route.model()` is the hook that uses `find` to load the data. The router does this when a promise is returned by `find`. By the time `setupController` is called it is assumed that you already have the model loaded, hence the second argument `model`. And this is exactly what the default setupController does, `controller.set('content', model)`. But if are loading additional data inside setupController, it's too late as far as the router is concerned, It's transition lifecycle has finished. Hence you have do this work manually.